# Visual Studio C# stored Procedure output value

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2012, linq-to-sql

I have a stored procedure with the name `Get_Visits`. The result is produced from a select statement.

```
select id, number, name ....
```

In Visual Studio I access the result:

```
List<DAL.Get_VisitsResult> resm = dc.Get_Visits(ctid, siteid, date).ToList<DAL.Get_VisitsResult>();

foreach (DAL.Get_VisitsResult m in resm)
{
    resm.id = 4
}
```

I altered the stored procedure so the result contains another column:

```
select id, new_id, number, name....
```

I refresh the stored procedure in `.dbml` file but I can't access the new column.

Only if I go by hand in file .designer.cs and edit the

```
public partial class Get_VisitsResult
{
        private string _Id;
        private string _new_Id;
        private string _name;
        .....
}
```

Shouldn't this file be updated whenever I update the stored procedure in Visual Studio?

***Problem solved by ... restarting the laptop***

Comment: just build your DAL.

Comment: I did that already

Comment: Have you tried turning VS off and back on again (seriously).

Comment: Yes. I deleted the sp saved my project turned off VS , turned on, insert the sp, save again but still the same...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using server explorer to drag and drop stored procedures in DBML, follow these steps.

1. DOUBLE Click on DBML file.
2. DELETE the stored procedure definition from it.
3. Refresh the SP in server explorer
4. DRAG and DROP it to DBML
5. Build The Project containing DBML.

This would work. :)

Comment: This is the exact way I do it whenever I update a stored procedure

Comment: Are you able to see the change while you right click and open SP from solution explorer ?